# what is the orientation of a stdout in C

Tags: c

The [GNU C manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Streams-and-I18N) says that:

> Being able to use the same stream for wide and normal operations comes
>   with a restriction: a stream can be used either for wide operations or
>   for normal operations.
>
> *[...]*
>
> It is important to never mix the use of wide and not wide
>   operations on a stream. There are no diagnostics issued. The
>   application behavior will simply be strange or the application will
>   simply crash. The `fwide` function can help avoiding this.

I have tried on vs2012, a `printf` followed immediately by a `wprintf`, and the simple program works properly.

Then my question is, what does the manual mean? When and why we should use `fwide` function?

Comment: What's the connection between vs2012 and Gnu c? Are you using an makefile Project to invoke gcc from visual Studio? Otherwise I don't get it...

Comment: @Constantin, sorry, it's because i don't have a Linux by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Streams-and-I18N) says, more fully:

> Being able to use the same stream for wide and normal operations comes
>   with a restriction: a stream can be used either for wide operations or
>   for normal operations. Once it is decided there is no way back. Only a
>   call to freopen or freopen64 can reset the orientation. The
>   orientation can be decided in three ways:
>
> - If any of the normal character functions is used (this includes the fread and fwrite functions) the stream is marked as not wide oriented.
> - If any of the wide character functions is used the stream is marked as wide oriented.
> - The fwide function can be used to set the orientation either way.
>
> It is important to never mix the use of wide and not wide operations
>   on a stream. There are no diagnostics issued. The application behavior
>   will simply be strange or the application will simply crash. The fwide
>   function can help avoiding this.

Note that the Microsoft documentation says their `fwide()` is "not implemented" (it's a no-op) and it "does not comply with the standard."

My reading of all this is that programs using glibc must not use both narrow and wide character functions on a single stream without reopening it.  Perhaps on Microsoft platforms there is no such restriction; perhaps even other libc implementations are more flexible.

Comment: and how to know the orientation of current stream? is there some kind of function can do this ？

Comment: @xusisme: Call `fwide(stream, 0)`.  Its return value will tell you the current stream orientation: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwide.3.html